# Can I get IdP Issuer URI and other info from an ADFS saml federation metadata file?

Tags: saml, adfs, idp

I've been provided a metadata.xml file from a client who is using ADFS, and had some questions getting this configured as an external SAML-based IdP. This is going to be integrated with a web application (LAMP stack, if that's relevant).

1) Can I extract the IdP Issuer URI from this xml file? I see entityID in the file, which is something like "http://sts.blablaba.com". Is this the same thing, or is this something I need to get separately from the client? Is this the same as "Relying party trust id"?

2) I see an `<X509Certificate>` element that looks like a public key. Is this the signing cert i need to verify the saml messages/asserts? Can I just copy/pasta this into a .crt or .pem file? "DigestMethod", "DigestValue" and "SignatureValue" are also present.

3) With an oauth2 flow, for instance, since it starts at the site, i can store redirects in a session, and send users to different pages depending on what they were initially trying to access. It seems like this would be possible with an SP initiated flow, but the client says this is going to be IdP initiated.  Is this type of post-login dynamic page redirection still possible, considering that the Relay State looks like a static value?

Comment: about LAMP , are you using mod_auth_mellon (on 'A') or simpleSAMLPHP (on 'P')?

wrt 1) the value of the Issuer URI would be the same as the value for EntityID
wrt 2) you need to extract the value of the 'X509Certificate' element and enclose it in PEM-boundary '-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----' , '-----END CERTIFICATE-----' to use it in a '.pem' file.

Comment: @BernhardThalmayr Thanks for the reply, it's a tremendous help. Actually, we're using a third party service (Okta), though I'm going to use simpleSAMLPHP to set up a mock external IdP for internal testing.

Comment: I guess Okta is the IdP side, but which implementation is used as SAML SP?

Comment: @BernhardThalmayr Wow, it's been a literal year since I received your help. I've since figured out all my SSO-related issues, thanks to your assist. If you'd like to leave a response below, I'll mark is as the accepted answer.

Comment: I'm glad you could solve your issue @sayajay